# Apostrophe is added when creating formula in Google Spreadsheet using C#

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

When I create a formula in Google Sheets via C#, the formula gets prepended with an apostrophe like so:

```
'=SUM(B3:B5)
```

With that apostrophe in the beginning, the formula is treated as string so it does not do what it is supposed to do. Can you help? Below is my code.

```
        var formula1 = "=SUM(B3:B5)";
        var formula2 = "=SUM(C3:C5";
        var formula3 = "=MAX(D3:D5)";

        List<object> list1 = new List<object>() { "Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date" };
        List<object> list2 = new List<object>() { "Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016" };
        List<object> list3 = new List<object>() { "Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016" };
        List<object> list4 = new List<object>() { "Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016" };
        List<object> list5 = new List<object>() { "Totals", formula1, formula2, formula3 };
        IList<IList<Object>> list = new List<IList<Object>>() { list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 };

        ValueRange VRange = new ValueRange();
        VRange.Range = range;
        VRange.Values = list;

        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest ar = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(VRange, spreadsheetId,range);
        ar.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW;
        var response2 = ar.Execute();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I got it. You just need to change the "RAW" to "USERENTERED" like this

```
ar.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
```